# Returning specific JSON format from Query Builder

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I'm using `Query Builder` to get results from multiple joins tables with this query :

```php
$products = DB::table('products as p')
              ->select(
                  'p.id',
                  'p.name',
                  'p.reference',
                  'p.price',
                  'i.path',
                  'i.name'
                )
              ->join('products_r_images as pri', 'pri.product_id', '=', 'p.id')
              ->join('images as i', 'i.id', '=', 'prd.image_id')
              ->get();
```

One product can have multiples images associated.

With the above query, I obtains this result :

```
[
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Test",
        reference: "ref-test",
        price: 123,
        image_path: "product/product-3/",
        image_name: "product_1.jpg"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "Test",
        reference: "ref-test",
        price: 123,
        image_path: "product/product-3/",
        image_name: "product_2.jpg"
    }
]
```

As you can see, two rows are returns for one product, while I would like to have documents datas returns in one row with something like that :

```
[
    {
        product_id: 3,
        name: "Test",
        reference: "ref-test",
        price: 123,
        image_path: "product/product-3/",
        image_name: 
        [
            "product_1.jpg", "product_2.jpg"
        ]
    }
]
```

Is there a way to do that directly with Query Builder, or another treatment is needed ?

Comment: Have you got `Eloquent` models set up for these tables?

Comment: Yes, I have set up for each table

Comment: And have you set the relationship up for images?

Comment: Do you mean a function in `Product` model returning `hasMany(App\Images)` ? If it is, no I didn't, because for this query I only use `Query Builder`.

Comment: Fair enough :) Just fyi, the relationship would be a `belongsToMany` not `hasMany`

Comment: You're right, my bad !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to use Query Builder for this then you should be able to:

```
$products = DB::table('products as p')
    ->select(
        'p.id',
        'p.name',
        'p.reference',
        'p.price',
        'i.path',
        'i.name'
    )
    ->join('products_r_images as pri', 'pri.product_id', '=', 'p.id')
    ->join('images as i', 'i.id', '=', 'prd.image_id')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->map(function ($products) {

        $product = $products->first();
        $product->image_name = $products->pluck('image_name');

        return $product;
    });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! But I have an error : `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::map()`

Comment: @Nenroz What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.4

Comment: @Nenroz Have you copied the query exactly i.e. you're still calling `get()` before the `groupBy()` and `map()`?

Comment: It was indeed the problem, thank you very much for you help !